# Get Bios serial number in perl

Tags: perl, serialization

I want to get the Bios serial number then check if it is exist in webpage content using Perl , I tried this code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::Simple;
my $serial = qx(wmic bios  GET SerialNumber 2>&1);
my $source = get("http://localhost/Check/serials.txt");
my $ff = "$serial";

if ("$source" =~ "$ff"){
    print "Serial Found ^_^\n";
}else{
    print "Sorry , Serial Not Found In Our Database !!\n";
}
```

* the URL `http://localhost/Check/serials.txt` have list of serial numbers.

But script always give me `Sorry , Serial Not Found In Our Database !!` but the serial number of my Bios is found !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here, all to do with the exact contents of various strings.

The WMIC command doesn't just hand back `61-1210-000747-00101111-071595-M747` because it's meant for a command-line interface and has to look nice in that context

***Note that I can't test this directly as my Windows system is hand-built and has no serial number***

Instead, it returns something like

```
"SerialNumber  \r\n61-1210-000747-00101111-071595-M747\r\n\r\n"
```

and searching for that in the `serials.txt` file on your intranet is pretty much bound to fail. You need to isolate the serial number from the surrounding text using something like this

```
my $response = qx(wmic bios GET SerialNumber);
my ($serial) = $response =~ /^SerialNumber\s+(\S+)/;
```

There is also a problem with using a regex pattern to search the contents of the `serials.txt` on your intranet. It would be best to parse the contents of that file properly, but you don't show what it looks like

Instead you can use `\Q...\E` in the regex pattern, so that any regex metacharacters that may be in the serial number are handled literally instead. You will als need to surround that in `\b...\b` so that a serial number like `123A` isn't "validated" because it happens to be a substring of `ABC-123AD-59F` in the `serials.txt` file

This should work for you

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use LWP::Simple 'get';
use Data::Dump 'dump';

use constant SERIALS_URL => 'http://localhost/Check/serials.txt';


my $response = qx(wmic bios GET SerialNumber);
my ($serial) = $response =~ /^SerialNumber\s+(\S+)/
        or die sprintf qq{Unexpect response %s\n    from WMIC}, dump $response;


my $source = get SERIALS_URL or die;


if ( $source =~ /\b\Q$serial\E\b/ ) {
    print "Serial Found\n";
}
else{
    print qq{Serial number "$serial" not found in our database};
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro ^_^

Answer (score -1):

You should add some debug output:

- print `$serial` to check if it's read correctly. Maybe you need to be root to read it?
- print `$source` to check if the file has been downloaded correctly.

You probably need to [`chomp $serial`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) to cut off any line break suffix.

The serial number might contain RegEx special chars (for example `. + * ( ) { } [ ] - ?`). Try

```
$ff = quotemeta($serial);
```

[`quotemeta` will escape all reserved chars](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

PS: There is no need to copy `$serial` to `$ff`. Just a waste of memory and CPU time unless you change it (like using `quotemeta`). You also don't need to put `" "` around variables used in source. Using them with RegEx is considered bad style. Try

```
if ($source =~ /$ff/){
```

Comment: I tried` print $serial` and the output is :
SerialNumber
NXV7VEM06332617BXXXXXX
But when i add quotemeta function the output become : 
\SerialNumber\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\XV7VEM06332617BXXXXXX\ \ \
\

Comment: Looks like there are some unprintable chars in the string. Try using `Data::Dumper` to see what's going on or try `print unpack("H*",$serial)` to get the hex representation of the string which should show you the chars (maybe ASCII-0 = `\x00`). You could also use a RegEx to extract the pure serial number from that string, something like `$serial =~ /Serial\W+(\w+)/; $ff = $1;`

Comment: The required information is buried within some layout text with Windows' CR LF as line terminators. It's very simple to extract using a regex, but there's no point in waving random operators at it. Neither `chomp` nor `quotemeta` will help here